# Identities for differential forms and vectorfields (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Recently I found the slides of a talk of J. E. Marsden, ([Differential Forms and Stokes' Theorem](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/wiki/uploads/cds202-08/home/Differential_Forms.pdf)). These slides introduce the required objects and summarize the basics of the corresponding theory.

In the last part some very useful formulas (identities) are given, which establish the relation between objects (vector fields and differential forms) and operators (Lie derivatives, Lie brackets, exterior derivative, wedge product, innterior product (= contraction)).

E.g. two of them are:

$$\iota_{[X,Y]} \alpha = \mathcal{L}_X \iota_Y \alpha - \iota_Y \mathcal{L}_X \alpha \qquad (1)$$

$$\mathcal{L}_{[X,Y]} \alpha = \mathcal{L}_X \mathcal{L}_Y \alpha - \mathcal{L}_Y \mathcal{L}_X \alpha \qquad (2)$$

for vector fields $X,Y$, a $k$-form $\alpha$ and $\mathcal{L}, \iota$ denoting the Lie-derivative and the interior product, respectively.

Probably, such formulas can be derived self-sufficiently from basic properties of the related objects.

**Q1:** Must this be done by choosing coordinates or is it always possible to argument without coordinates (like in the proof of Cartans "magic formula")?

On the other hand it would be nice to know a reference where these (and other) identities are published (including their proofs).

**Q2:** Where to look for the derivation of such identities?

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the slides you linked, it looks like they can all be done without working in coordinates. Do you perhaps have specific identities in mind for which you mean ' possible to argue without coordinates.' You mentioned Cartan's magic formula can be proved without working in local coordinates, and so can $\mathcal L_{[X,Y]}\alpha=\mathcal L_X(\mathcal L_Y\alpha)-\mathcal L_Y(\mathcal L_X\alpha)$ as it is just the Jacobi identity for a Lie-bracket.

For your second question, all of those identities can be found in most introduction to differential geometry books. Check out John Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" and Loring Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds." The identities will either be derived or left as an exercise. But those left as an exercise can probably be found in another introduction to differential geometry book.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I will have a look. Though, my hope was to find a single place where _all_ useful formulas are derived step by step. Like a compendium. While I agree that deriving them as an exercise deepens the insight, I have a different desire. As an engineer I want to use diff. geometry as a tool and I do not want to study it (like a mathematician). So, step by step derivations would allow me to understand the concepts much faster and to concentrate on my core questions. E.g. you say, that (2) its just the Jacobi identity, but I will take some time until I see it.

Comment: I see. Both books above contain most those identities with step by step derivations. As for the Jacobi identity remark, it won't take you time to see it once you learn the fundamental fact that $\mathcal L_XY=[X,Y]$. Although, in your notation $\alpha$ is a 1-form so it does require a little bit more work. I would check out both references I listed above and search for the chapters on the Lie derivative and interior multiplication.